# javascript media query - loading HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, media-queries

I want an HTML element (`<p>HTML element</p>`) to load on the page ONLY when the screen size is above a certain width.

I don't want it hidden; I want it to be removed entirely when the screen size is below 600, and loading when the screen size is above 600.

I tried

```
if (window.matchMedia('screen and (min-width: 600px)')){
   $('body').append('<p>HTML element</p>');
}
```

but it's not working for me. Any clues?

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to simply show/hide based on a media query? Do you want the element removed from the DOM after it has been added already?

Comment: Clue 1: that's not remotely valid Javascript. You should have a [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) full of errors.

Comment: Question: what do you wish to happen if someone resizes the browser? Should the element be removed, reinserted, etc. as it goes past the 600px boundary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.matchMedia()` returns an object, you need to check for `matches` property:

```
if (window.matchMedia('screen and (min-width: 600px)').matches){...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why those media queries? `$(document).width()` would be a solution.

```
if($(document).width()>600){
    $('body').append('<p>HTML element</p>');
}
```

Comment: What if window has some vertical scroll bars? Checking for document width isn't relevant solution especially if some CSS media queries are set for styling purpose

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( document.body.clientWidth > 600 )
{
  "add element"
}
else
{
  "Remove element"
}
```